# single vim statusline for all windows

Tags: configuration, editor, vim

How do you setup vim statusline in way that it doesn't split into two status lines when spliting the window vertically ? and have it display information only for the active window.

Answer (score 2):

Not feasible, as `'laststatus'` is a global option.

Guess you should check for 'title' or 'tabline' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Neovim 0.7 has global statusline.

add:

```
set laststatus=3
```

to your `init.vim`.

You can make the thick line thin by:

```
highlight WinSeparator guibg=None
```